# Spark VM box NOT getting created in windows

Tags: windows, apache-spark, vagrant, virtualbox

I am new to spark. Infact, I started learning it from today from edX.I am setting up my environment in windows so that sparkvm could be used.Following are the upto date Installations that I did on my PC.

Installed Virtualbox
Installed Vagrant

created a directory

C:\Users\Macro\myvagrant

and copy VagrantFile from (https://github.com/spark-mooc/mooc-setup/archive/master.zip)

Then I executed the following command from the specified path in dos.
**vagrant up** but the following message is coming every time.
[image]

How would I get out of this mess?

**Update:**

After downloading the file and executing the suggested code.I got following error.

[image]

Comment: I followed the same course last year and used the following command to set it up `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` but it seems like vagrant found it automatically for you. Are you by any chance behind a firewall or have specific settings for your network ? You might want to dig in the HTTP and HTTPS settings. Did you install VirtualBox as administrator ?

Comment: Why not just install Spark directly on your machine? Spark needs memory to run its jobs fast, so you are only limiting it by placing it in a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vagrant is not able to download the box from its cloud.

you can try the following:

- if you're behind a proxy, set the proxy :

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://your.proxyhost.server:port/
  export https_proxy=https://your.proxyhost.server:port/
  vagrant up
  ```
- download the box directly and install: download from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/sparkmooc/boxes/base2/versions/0.0.7.1/providers/virtualbox.box directly or you can use a downloader tool (such as wget as below)

  ```
  wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/sparkmooc/boxes/base2/versions/0.0.7.1/providers/virtualbox.box
  ```

Then you'll need to install the box

```
vagrant box add sparkmooc/base2 <location of downloaded box file>
vagrant up
```

Comment: I downloaded the file and used the command but now a new error is coming. Please check my updated question.